# How to keep track of numbered variables made from function call in while loop. How many are there?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I'm writing a small project using python,
But now I'm in trouble.

I made some code like this:

```
START_BUTTONS = ("button1", "button2")
markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
lengthof = len(START_BUTTONS)
countn = 0
while (countn < lengthof):
  exec("itembtn" + str(countn) + " = types.KeyboardButton(START_BUTTONS[" + str(countn) + "])")
  countn = countn + 1
```

So, this will parse something like this (unitl the tuple ends):

```
itembtn0 = types.KeyboardButton(START_BUTTONS[0])
itembtn1 = types.KeyboardButton(START_BUTTONS[1])
```

and...

So those variables are usable later.

But, my problem is here. I want to check how many of those variables are there (itembtn0 itembtn1 itembtn2 itembtn3...) and put them like this:

```
markup.row(itembtn0, itembtn1, itembtn2)
```

so , if there were 5 of those, it will return something like this:
    markup.row(itembtn0, itembtn1, itembtn2, itembtn3, itembtn4)

Actually I have no idea for what I should write.

Thanks for help! & Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: isn't that what countn does?

Comment: You are trying to create numbered variables, which can in all cases be replaced by an array.

Comment: You do **not** need `exec` for this. You should be putting your buttons into a container, eg a list, or perhaps a dictionary.

Comment: benten nope not that, its what lengthof does, but it only gives the length and I dont have any idea how to loop those variables.
@JulienD omg.. Ill take a look at that tnx

Comment: I Tried @2Ring I got SyntaxError. (I think 'instance cannot be converted to int' I forgot it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create numbered variables, which can in all cases be replaced by an array. Try something simple instead:

```
START_BUTTONS = ("button1", "button2")
markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
itembtn = []
for btn in START_BUTTONS:
  itembtn.append(types.KeyboardButton(btn))
```

Access it with

```
itembtn[0]
itembtn[1]
etc.
```

And you can know how many there are:

```
len(itembtn)
```

I am not sure about your markup function, but you can pass the whole array as parameters like this:

```
markup.row(*itembtn)
```

Comment: OMG Thanks it did the trick! only i changed something: `itembtn.append(types.KeyboardButton(countn))` & added `countn = countn + 1` and it did it. Really thanks